# How to filter top N records under each category in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

[image: Input]

I have a table as shown above. I would like to filter the above dataframe such that it displays only the top 2 products under each category in terms of sales. So the output should look like something below.

[image: Output]

I could try building loops and iterate and get this done. I was hoping if there's a quicker way of doing this.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'Products':['abc','xyz','def','nop','hjk','qrs'],'Sales':[1,2,3,4,5,2]})
```

Comment: It would be nice to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: plz provide input by code or text. we need copyable somthing to solve your problem.

Comment: `df.set_index('Products').groupby('Category')['Sales'].nlargest(2).reset_index()`?

Comment: This appears to take too long. My dataset exceeds 2M records

Answer (score 2):

Lets us rank the rows based on `Sales` column

```
df[df.groupby('Category')['Sales'].rank('dense', ascending=False) <= 2]
```

Result

```
  Category Products  Sales
1        A      xyz      2
2        A      def      3
3        B      nop      4
4        B      hjk      5
```

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve the original indexes of the records so we can trace their origin in future if needed (e.g. to merge or mask records):

```
(
    df
    .groupby('Category')
    .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'Sales'))
    .reset_index(0, drop=True)
)
```

Notes:

- [pandas.DataFrame.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)
- [pandas.Series.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)